# Getting value from an object

Tags: php

I have the following object, and I'm trying to get some values from it. Here is a snippet:

```
WP_Query Object
(
    [query] => Array
        (
            [category_name] => Beauty
            [numberposts] => -1
            [posts_per_page] => 4
            [post_type] => post
            [post_status] => publish
            [orderby] => date
            [order] => DESC
            [paged] => 1
        )

    [query_vars] => Array

        (
            [category_name] => beauty
            [numberposts] => -1
            [posts_per_page] => 4
            [post_type] => post
            [post_status] => publish
            [orderby] => date
            [order] => DESC
            [paged] => 1
            [error] => 
            [m] => 
            [p] => 0
            [post_parent] => 
            [subpost] => 
            [subpost_id] => 
            [attachment] => 
            [attachment_id] => 0
```

How would I get:

`[paged] => 1`?

I have tried the following, but neither work:

```
$category_query->paged; 
$category_query->query->paged;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have to traverse objects with `->` and arrays with `[ ]`:

```
$category_query->query['paged'];
```

Because `$category_query` is an object and `query` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
$category_query->query['paged'];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an object of arrays so you'd need to do..
    `$category_query->query['paged'];`

Traverse objects with `->` and arrays with `[ ]`